# installed pandas but still can't import it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I already installed it with `pip3 install pandas` and using python3.7 but when I try to import pandas and run the code error popping up.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/barbie/Python/Test/test.py", line 1, in 
>       import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

and if I try to install again.. it says this.

> pip3 install 
>   pandas Requirement already satisfied: pandas in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.23.4) Requirement already
>   satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
>   pandas) (2018.9) Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.15.4)
>   Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.7.5)
>   Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
>   python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.12.0)

Comment: Is your test.py using python or python3? In the same directory what does `python --version` or  `which python` return?

Comment: when I create Test folder with Pycharm I choose 3.7 then isn't test.py too using python3.7? @OllieinPGH

Comment: Have you tried installing any other module previously? and did it work? 
Is this the only python installation on your system?

Comment: default python2.7 comes with the mac. @ParvBanks

Comment: One alternative is you could use Anaconda.. but it'll create entire new environment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using pycharm you can go to File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter.

There you'll get a list of all the packages installed with the current python that pycharm is using. There is a '+' sign on the right of the window that you can use to install new packages, just enter pandas there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have more than one installation of Python.

You should check where your installed packages should be saved with the following

```
import os
os.path
```

and then install using the following terminal instruction

```
pip3 install pandas -t /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
```

where, of course, you should substitute the path with the one that Python gives you as output.

Comment: thank you, but it says this::  pip3 install pandas -t /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py
ERROR: Target path exists but is not a directory, will not continue.

Comment: try with pip3 install pandas -t /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.